# regex help, find first 3 occurrences of a keyword and str_ireplace the content

Tags: php, regex, string, text-parsing

Given a block of text, I need to parse it for the existing of a keyword. Then on the first appearance of the keyword, I need to wrap bold tags around it (if it doesn't already have them), on the second appearance of the keyword, italics, and on the third, underline.

Example using the keyword "**help**":

This is some text with the keyword "help". If you can help, I really appreciate it. Thanks for the help! If there are any more occurrences of the keyword **help**, I'll ignore them.

Would be rewritten to be...

This is some text with the keyword "<b>help</b>". If you can <em>help</em>, I really appreciate it. Thanks for the <u>help</u>! If there are any more occurrences of the keyword **help**, I'll ignore them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you need a PHP based solution because you mentioned `str_ireplace`.

You can do it using [**preg_replace_callback**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php).
This function is similar to `preg_replace` but calls a user-defined callback function whose return value will be used for replacement.

To keep track of the occurrence number I've used a `static` variable in the callback function.

```
$keyword = 'help';

// the callback function
function fun($matches)
{
        static $count = 0;

        // switch on $count and later increment $count.
        switch($count++) {
                case 0: return '<b>'.$matches[1].'</b>';   // 1st time..use bold
                case 1: return '<em>'.$matches[1].'</em>'; 
                case 2: return '<u>'.$matches[1].'</u>';
                default: return $matches[1];              // don't change others.
        }
}

// search for keyword separated by word boundaries.
// if present call the callback function.
$text = preg_replace_callback("/\b($keyword)\b/","fun",$text);
```

[**Code In Action**](http://www.ideone.com/JukzK)

Comment: Thanks codaddict! Works like a charm!

Comment: @coaddict, this works great with one exception: It does not respect if the keyword appears inside an html tag such as h1, h2, img (as alt attribute), etc. (I know that was not a requirement of my original ?) Any ideas how it can be altered to skip over keywords that are enclosed in a named tag?

Comment: Example: if the preparsed content is "This <strong>is a test post string</strong> and the keyword is "test post", it results in doubling of the strong tags like so (next comment)...

Comment: <strong>is a <strong>test post<strong> string</strong>